# Looking for a webcomic where the basic premise is that the weather change is a huge threat

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I'm looking for a webcomic I've read in the latter part of 00s/early 10s. I have found it by browsing through a huge database of webcomics by checking out tags that seemed appealing.

At the time it looked professionally made at the time, similar in esthetics to the "Outsider" webcomic. I have a faint recollection that the pages were roughly standard A4 in dimension.

It started with a backstory of the setting: in the near future, weather got wild, with massive storms happening all the time. Tools were built to combat this and were attached to futuristic-looking aircrafts that were combating it. The narration spoke with accompanying pictures about how first generation of weather controlling airships (civilian ships were quickly outfitted with the weather control tools) was losing the battle, but then the second generation (purposed-built aircraft) went into service and everything was Ok.

The story proper started with a crew on one of the second generation ships long after the victory itself. They have learned of a wild storm nearby that wasn't supposed to be there, and then I've decided that "wow it starts slowly, but maybe it picks up the pace later, I'll continue at another day" and I never did.

While the situations seems quite specific the generic terms make it surprisingly hard to google, and I've started wondering how it all went on, so... Is anyone familiar with it?

Comment: What database did you find it through?

Comment: @Laurel I do not know. I have only tried using it once, but wasn't really happy with the results and never used it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Storm Corps* which you can read on [The Storm Corps Archive](http://stormcorps.comicgenesis.com/d/20021103.html). I was looking for it as well.

Taken from [The Webcomic List](http://www.thewebcomiclist.com/p/484/storm-corps):

> In the year 2175, the Humans and the Duzand build an interplanetary warpgate in orbit to link their civilizations. But in 2195, the warpgates shatter, raining exotic energies on the two worlds, causing super storms that down spaceships and destroy cities. The scientists of both species construct or reengineer ships with the ability to fight the unnatural storms. These ships are manned by the brave men, women, and Duzand of the Storm Corps!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you [edit] your answer to clarify why you think _Storm Corps_ is the correct answer? Specifying plot points that match is a good way to do this. Linking and quoting sources can be helpful as well.

Comment: I've added a short description, as well as a link to read the comic online. The site they moved to (stormcorps.com) does look like it's no longer up and running though.

Comment: That's it, thank you so much! Huh, it looks way different than I remembered! I mostly wondered how the plot would develop when an already defeated weather seemed to be the main antagonist.